# Specific view has been scrolled out of the list view or not?

Tags: android, listview

i'am writing an app that has a ListView of videos and if the user plays one of them and scrolls the list ,so that the specific view is no longer visible on the screen, the video must be paused and MediaPlayer should be released.

So my question is that is there any way to know a view's been scrolled out in ListView not in ScrollView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            //if the result is false so mediaPlayer must be released
            if (videoCurrentPosition != -1 && !checkExistence(firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount)) adapter.releaseMediaPlayer();

        }
    });
```

videoCurrentPosition shows the position of the item that i've clicked. It's been set by -1 beacause poisition starts from 0 in adapter.

```
private Boolean checkExistence(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount) {


    for (int i = firstVisibleItem; i <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount - 1); i++) {

        // if it's true so our view is inside the list (on screen now)
        if (videoCurrentPosition == i) return true;

    }

    // if it's false so our view is'nt inside the list (not screen now)
    return false;

}
```